# error with callback function

Tags: callback, void, point-cloud-library

I am trying to register a keyboard callback function to a 3D viewer using the Point Cloud Library API.

Todo this I do:

```
viewer->registerKeyboardCallback(&(RailExtraction::keyboard_callback), (void*)(&gt_data));
```

But I get the following error message:

```
note: no known conversion for argument 1 from 'void (RailExtraction< pcl::PointXYZI >::*) 
(const pcl::visualization::KeyboardEvent&, void*)' to 'void (*)(const pcl::visualization::KeyboardEvent&, void*)'
```

I am trying to understand the error message.  I understand what `void` and `void *` mean but what does `void(*)(...)` or `void(RailExtraction< pcl::PointXYZI >::*>(...)` mean ??

Comment: after doing some reading, I understand that `void(*)(...)` and `void(RailExtraction<pcl::PointXYZI>::*>` are the function pointer argument but I still have no Idea how to fix the error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured out the problem  I am using the wrong version of `registerKeyBoardCallBack`.  I am currently trying to use this signature:

`registerKeyboardCallback (void (*callback) (const pcl::visualization::KeyboardEvent&, void*), void* cookie = NULL)`

But I should be using this signature:
`registerKeyboardCallback (void (T::*callback) (const pcl::visualization::KeyboardEvent&, void*), T& instance, void* cookie = NULL)`

This is because my `keyboard_callback` function is part of a class and therefore I need to specify the instance of the class so that the compiler can figure out which instance the `keyboard_callback` function to use. Therefore my new call to `registerKeyboardCallBack` looks like this:

viewer->registerKeyboardCallback(&RailExtraction::keyboard_callback, *this, (void*)&gt_data);